# Tkinter Import Error in NetBeans

Tags: python, netbeans, tkinter

I am working with python in NetBeans 7.4. I am trying to import Tkinter and use it. But it is giving this error:

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I tried 'import Tkinter' in python command line and it is working fine in that.

How can I configure Tk in Python?

Answer (score 0):

tkinter (Tkinter in 2.x) is a Python-coded stdlib module that imports the compiled C-coded _tkinter module that connects to tcl and tk compiled-C shared libraries.  `import tkinter` will fail if any of the 4 files is damaged, missing, or misplaced (which is seen as missing).  I know nothing about NetBeans, but if it uses its own private copy of python instead of the installed version that works, such a copy might have been compiled without including _tkinter by changing the compile configuration file.  I believe this is the meaning of 'not configured for Tk'.

On my Windows machine, _tkinter.pyd (a python-specific .dll), tcl85.dll, and tk85.dll are all in .../python27/DLLs/.  In NetBeans python, you might try `import os; os.getcwd()` to see what binary NetBeans is using.

Answer (score 0):

instead try

```
from tkinter import *
```